# Pattern filters in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to make a pattern route, to redirect users to login page when they are not logged in.
I searched but couldn't find a solution. as always Laravel's Documentation is useless!

I have this in my `filter.php`

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});

Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
return Auth::basic();
});
```

And this route in my `routes.php`

```
Route::when('/*', 'auth' );
```

but It's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: What is not working, can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want whenever a user goes to `http://mywebsite.com/public/` , IF he/she is not logged in before, automatically redirects to /login page to login. and * is because I want this rule for all my pages. But with above code, it's not doing as expected.

Comment: Do you have a `login` route, how it looks like ? How did you declare the login route ? What's haappenning now ?

Comment: This is my routes.php file:
`Route::when('/*', 'auth' );` 
`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex' );`
`Route::get('/login', 'UserController@getLogin');`

and this is my filters.php file:

`Route::filter('auth', function(){ if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('/login'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the route declaration for login like this

```
Route::get( '/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UserController@getLogin') );
```

In your `filters.php` use

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::route('login');
});
```

So, you can use

```
Route::when('*', 'auth' );
```

You can also use

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function ()
{
    // Define all routes here with auth
    Route::get('my_first_route', function(){ /... });
    Route::post('my_second_route', 'MyController@myAction');
});
```

Comment: `auth` and `auth.basic` are Laravel's pre defined filters. I've not defined them.

Comment: not working. I've done this before in laravel 3. but I can't in laravel 4 :(

Comment: Thank you, Route::group worked for me. also still wildcard routing does not work!. +1 for your reply and time :)